# Cannot create property 'inject' on string 'reactiveData'

Tags: vue.js

After updating to vue 2.5.8 I've started getting this error: `Cannot create property 'inject' on string 'reactiveData'`

My dependencies are as follows:

```
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "buefy": "^0.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.0.5",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "pusher-js": "^4.2.1",
    "vanilla-tilt": "^1.4.1",
    "vue": "2.5.8",
    "vue-chartjs": "^2.8.7",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vue2-google-maps": "0.8.0",
    "vuex": "^2.4.1"
```

Would love to know how I can get around this one.

Comment: It would really help to see the code that is generating this error.  Please include line numbers to show exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: I have no idea what code is causing the issue though. Only difference I make is updating the version of Vue